# parse.com cannot get values from object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a backend on Parse.com. I am trying to get a value from a User object in javascript cloud code, but it is not working. Let's say I am trying to get the email.

Here is the cloud code that retrieves a User Object...

```
var printUser = function(){

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.get( "2FSYI1hoJ8");  
query.find({
  success: function(result) {

    console.log(result);
  }
});
};
```

and here is the result of that search...

> I2014-03-07T22:43:21.894Z]
>   [{"email":"a@a.com","phoneVerified":true,"randomNumber":99862,"toPhone":"+13035551212","username":"a","objectId":"2FSYI1hoJ8","createdAt":"2014-03-02T21:07:02.192Z","updatedAt":"2014-03-07T22:43:13.103Z","__type":"Object","className":"_User"}]

So I know the search works. I tried using 'result.get("email")', 'result.email', 'result("email")' and any variation I could find in their documentation to get the email value, but nothing works.

The error codes vary based on what is being called, so I will spare you that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of objects (with only one element), not a standalone object. The first element in your array is your result object:

```
result[0].email
```

will get you the email property of that object.

Comment: Very close... because it is Parse.com, turns out it needed to be result[0].get("email"). Thank you very much! (another day of too much time spent because I am missing the details...)

Comment: For future reference, if you only expect a single result you can use `query.first()` which will prevent this issue